# How to use instance of a class somewhere else in the code

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

In `MainBox` I have a Button `Add` and I have created a method that add `Template` on the screen when the Button is pressed.
In `add_template` from `MainBox` I have created an instance `template_instance` for `Template` class.
How can I use that instance that I have created in other classes, or in other side of code. For example when I press on the `Template` in main screen, it opens a new screen `Scr2`. In `Scr2` is a `Delete Button`, and there I want to call `template_instance.del_template()` and to Delete the Template that was pressed.
I want to open a Popup Window and there to modify or to change  `parameter1, parameter2, parameter3` , or to use `function1(), function2()`  of that `template_instance` somewhere else in the code.
And if I added multiple `Template` in the main screen to know that functions or parameters called refer to that certain Widget.

Here I put a code for a clear understanding:

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Scr1(Screen):
    pass
class Scr2(Screen):
    pass
class Dialog(Popup):
    pass

class MainBox(BoxLayout):
    def add_template(self):
        template_instance = Template()
        self.ids.add_template.add_widget(template_instance)

class Template(BoxLayout, Button):
    name = StringProperty()
    parameter1 = StringProperty()
    parameter2 = BooleanProperty()
    parameter3 = NumericProperty()
    def del_template(self):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
    def open_popup(self):
        pp = Dialog()
        pp.open()
    def function1(self):
        pass
    def function2(self):
        pass
```

```
WindowManager:
    Scr1:
        MainBox:
    Scr2:

<Scr2>:
    name: 'Scr2'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Do you want to delete?'
        Button:
            text: 'Delete'
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr1'

<Scr1>:
    name: 'Scr1'

<MainBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: add_template
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        text: 'Add'
        on_release: root.add_template()

<Template>:
    on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr2'
    CheckBox:
        size_hint: 0.15, 1
    Label:
        text: root.name
    Button:
        text: 'Open'
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.5 }
        on_release: root.open_popup()
```

Comment: Firstly, inheriting from different widgets, in general, not a good idea. Secondly, as it seems that `ScreenManager` is your `root` widget, you can use method `get_screen` of `Screen` class (perhaps with some ids).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmvNutNqKWM check this